# Installation for @ionic-native/camera

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Am getting error while Installation for @ionic-native/camera

Error is
A package version that is forbidden by your security policy
It was specified as a dependency

Answer (score 0):

@ionic-native deprecated on ionic6 and replaced with @awesome-cordova-plugins.

```
npm install cordova-plugin-camera
npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/camera
ionic cap sync
```